# In Android studio when trying to open my emulator it shows error

Tags: android

If I tried to open and run an emulator in My AVD Studio it will showing the error like the below.

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Comment: It means that you need to turn on HAXM, which requires operating system and BIOS support.  Make sure its enabled in BIOS, and make sure whatever OS you're running on has the proper settings enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open SDK Manager and Download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) if you haven't.

2) Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory Go to extras > intel > Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe".

In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology (vt,vt-x) is not enabled". Go to your BIOS settings and enable Hardware Virtualization.

3) Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

Comment: If you find my answer correct then please mark on right